# VB.Net Delete Selected Row in DataGridView MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

This the code that I use. The message box is appearing but when I select yes, the selected row is not deleted at the datagridview and database.

```vb
Private Sub Delete2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete2.Click
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=;database=equipment"

        Try
            If Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim intStdID As Char = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells("asset_code").Value
                    'open connection
                    If Not MySqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        MySqlConn.Open()
                    End If

                    'delete data
                    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
                    cmd.Connection = MySqlConn
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM equipment.equipment" & intStdID
                    Dim res As DialogResult
                    res = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to DELETE the selected Row?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                    If res = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Else : Exit Sub
                    End If
                    'refresh data
                    Load_table()

                    'close connection
                    MySqlConn.Close()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
        End Try
```

Comment: Your SQL query has no `WHERE` clause and you are concatenating the integer directly onto the end of the word "equipment". Would recommend parameterizing this query as it will help prevent SQL injection and will help solve this issue as well.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions like that, you would see a useful message if you logged or otherwise handled the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM equipment.equipment" & intStdID
```

It attempts to append the ID value from the selected cell to the SQL statement. However, it seems like this is *just* the ID value. You also need the `WHERE ID=` portion for the query.

Moreover, it's using this ID value in the query in the **wrong way**.  It's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to include data in a query. You **must** use parameterized queries.

The code below demonstrates this, as well as several other better patterns for this method, with the caveat that I had to guess as some names and types from your database.

```
Private Sub Delete2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete2.Click
    If Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count = 0 OrElse Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim res As DialogResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to DELETE the selected Row?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If res <> DialogResult.Yes Then Exit Sub

    Dim intStdID As Char = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells("asset_code").Value
    Dim SQL as String = "DELETE * FROM equipment.equipment WHERE equipment.StdID= @AssetCode"

    Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=;database=equipment"), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = intStdID            
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Load_table()
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that work in VB? I thought multiple variables in a `using` block had to be of the same `Type`.

Comment: @Crowcoder It does work, though it cheats a bit (it's possible in rare circumstances for the 2nd object to not get disposed immediately). But in more than a decade that's never caused a problem for any code I've been privileged to look at. Now if the 2nd object were the connection, instead of just the command, I might be more careful with it. C# allows getting around the problem by stacking multiple `using` blocks without increasing indentation and with only one set of braces. Sadly Visual Studio for VB is aggressive about the indentation and there's no avoiding the multiple `End Using` lines

Comment: Interesting. In c# you cannot use different types as a comma separated list inside a `using`.

Comment: that's correct... but C# lets you easily stack multiple separate using blocks, with special handling even in Visual Studio to change the normal indentation helpers. This is VB's closest equivalent (the comma is actually creating a new statement). It's definitely not perfect, but I've used this pattern a lot and seen it used around even more, and I've never known it to cause a problem as long as the connection object comes first.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn tried your code, message box appears but when I click yes the selected row is still not deleted

Comment: @kai And when you step through with the debugger does it run the ExecuteNonQuery() line? Does it throw an exception?